# Cypress how to upload png, csv, docx

Tags: javascript, file-upload, cypress, attachment

I want to upload a .csv, .png, .docx file types to an web element using cypress. I have tried following ways but nothing happens on the web app. does some one know what might be the issue ??

```
const fileName = 'csvfile.csv';
            cy.fixture('myfiles/csvfile.csv').then(fileContent => {
                cy.get(locator).attachFile({
                    fileContent,
                    fileName: 'csvfile.csv',
                    mimeType: 'application/csv'
                })
            })
```

I tried with mimeType as "image/png" for png but it did not work.
I have used import statement for cypress-upload in support/commands.js but still not working.

Comment: What type is 'fileContent' that you receive? Not that cy.fixture loads it eg. as binary.  You can specify 'encoding' explicitely https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/fixture#Arguments

Comment: It is actually an empty file. I just need to upload in my web app @9ilsdx9rvj0lo

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this

```
const fileName = 'csvfile.csv';  
        cy.fixture('myfiles/csvfile.csv', "binary")
          .then(Cypress.Blob.binaryStringToBlob)
          .then((fileContent) => {
        cy.get(locator).attachFile({
          fileContent,
          filePath: "myfiles/csvfile.csv",
          fileName: "csvfile.csv",
        });
```

Comment: did not work for me. The test case passed but the file did not attach @ItsNotAndy